# JSON object syntax

Tags: json

I understand that the following refers to a JSON object. Can anyone tell me what it exactly means? (There is an arrow function.)

```
export default createContainer(()=>{
      return {
         ledgerNames:LedgerMasters.find({}).fetch().map((row,index)
           =>{return (row.ledgerName)}),journalsList:Journals.find({}).fetch() }},JournalEntry);
```

Comment: *"I understand that the following refers to a JSON object."* Not at all. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). It seems you have JavaScript code, so what you have there is an *object literal*. *"Can anyone tell me what it exactly means?"* What specifically is unclear?

Comment: Am I correct that ledgerNames gets assigned to LedgerMasters.find({}).fetch().map((row,index)
           =>{return (row.ledgerName)})                                                                      Same way journalsList gets assigned Journals.find({}).fetch()...but what is Journals.find({}).fetch()

Comment: I went thru this https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/